# Sum the value of some hash keys inside an array

Tags: ruby

I try to search but any solution doesn't work.

I have this array of hashes

```
[{:smartphone=>"Galaxy Note 8 - Samsung", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"ZenFone 4 Pro - Asus", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Xperia XZ1 - Sony", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Mate 10 Pro - Huawei", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"V30 - LG", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"One Plus 5T", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Pixel 2 XL - Google", :votes=>1}, {:smartphone=>"Nokia 8", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Z2 Force - Moto", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"U11 - HTC", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"iPhone X - Apple", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"iPhone X - Apple", :votes=>1}, {:smartphone=>"iPhone X - Apple", :votes=>1}, {:smartphone=>"Galaxy Note 8 - Samsung", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"ZenFone 4 Pro - Asus", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Xperia XZ1 - Sony", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Mate 10 Pro - Huawei", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"V30 - LG", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"One Plus 5T", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Pixel 2 XL - Google", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Nokia 8", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Z2 Force - Moto", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"U11 - HTC", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Galaxy Note 8 - Samsung", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"ZenFone 4 Pro - Asus", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Xperia XZ1 - Sony", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Mate 10 Pro - Huawei", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"V30 - LG", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"One Plus 5T", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Pixel 2 XL - Google", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Nokia 8", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Z2 Force - Moto", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"U11 - HTC", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Galaxy Note 8 - Samsung", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"ZenFone 4 Pro - Asus", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Xperia XZ1 - Sony", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Mate 10 Pro - Huawei", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"V30 - LG", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"One Plus 5T", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Pixel 2 XL - Google", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Nokia 8", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Z2 Force - Moto", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"U11 - HTC", :votes=>1}, {:smartphone=>"iPhone X - Apple", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Galaxy Note 8 - Samsung", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"ZenFone 4 Pro - Asus", :votes=>1}, {:smartphone=>"Xperia XZ1 - Sony", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Mate 10 Pro - Huawei", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"V30 - LG", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"One Plus 5T", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Pixel 2 XL - Google", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Nokia 8", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Z2 Force - Moto", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"U11 - HTC", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"iPhone X - Apple", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Galaxy Note 8 - Samsung", :votes=>1}, {:smartphone=>"ZenFone 4 Pro - Asus", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"One Plus 5T", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Pixel 2 XL - Google", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"U11 - HTC", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Z2 Force - Moto", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Nokia 8", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Pixel 2 XL - Google", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"One Plus 5T", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"V30 - LG", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Galaxy Note 8 - Samsung", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Xperia XZ1 - Sony", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"V30 - LG", :votes=>1}, {:smartphone=>"Z2 Force - Moto", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"iPhone X - Apple", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"iPhone X - Apple", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"ZenFone 4 Pro - Asus", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Mate 10 Pro - Huawei", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Nokia 8", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"U11 - HTC", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Mate 10 Pro - Huawei", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Xperia XZ1 - Sony", :votes=>0}]
```

And I want to sum the votes for every smartphone

I try with

```
results.group_by { |hash1| hash1[:smartphone] }.map do |_,v|
  v.inject do |ele_hash2,ele_hash1|
      puts ele_hash2
      puts ele_hash1
     ele_hash2.merge(ele_hash1) {|k,o,n| k == :vote ? o+n : o }
  end
end
```

But it returns me

```
[{:smartphone=>"Galaxy Note 8 - Samsung", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"ZenFone 4 Pro - Asus", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Xperia XZ1 - Sony", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Mate 10 Pro - Huawei", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"V30 - LG", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"One Plus 5T", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Pixel 2 XL - Google", :votes=>1}, {:smartphone=>"Nokia 8", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"Z2 Force - Moto", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"U11 - HTC", :votes=>0}, {:smartphone=>"iPhone X - Apple", :votes=>0}]
```

And it's not correct, Apple iPhone X has 1 vote for example.
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `arr` is your array of hashes, you can do the following.

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |g,h| h[g[:smartphone]] += g[:votes] }
  #=> {"Galaxy Note 8 - Samsung"=>1, "ZenFone 4 Pro - Asus"=>1,
  #    "Xperia XZ1 - Sony"=>0, "Mate 10 Pro - Huawei"=>0, "V30 - LG"=>1,
  #    "One Plus 5T"=>0, "Pixel 2 XL - Google"=>1, "Nokia 8"=>0, 
  #    "Z2 Force - Moto"=>0, "U11 - HTC"=>1, "iPhone X - Apple"=>2}
```

`Hash.new(0)` creates a hash with a default value of zero (sometimes called a *counting hash*). See [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new). This mean if a hash `h` so defined has no key `k`, `h[k]` returns the default value, here zero. (The hash is not changed.) The expression `h[g[:smartphone]] += g[:votes]` expands to

```
h[g[:smartphone]] = h[g[:smartphone]] + g[:votes]
```

When a hash `g` in the array has a value `"iPhone X - Apple"` for the key `:smartphone`, the above expression becomes

```
h["iPhone X - Apple"] = h["iPhone X - Apple"] + g[:votes]
```

The first time the value `"iPhone X - Apple"` for `:smartphone` in `g` is encountered the hash `h` being constructed does not have a key `"iPhone X - Apple"`. `h["iPhone X - Apple"]` on the right side of the equality above is therefore set equal to the default value, zero, so we have

```
h["iPhone X - Apple"] = g[:votes]
```

The next time `g[:smartphone]` is found to equal `"iPhone X - Apple"`, `h["iPhone X - Apple"]` on the right side of the equality will equal `g[:votes]`, so the default value will not apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
input.
  group_by { |h| h[:smartphone] }.
  map { |k, v| [k, v.reduce(0) { |acc, h| acc + h[:votes] }] }.
  to_h
#⇒ {
#  "Galaxy Note 8 - Samsung" => 1,
#     "Mate 10 Pro - Huawei" => 0,
#                  "Nokia 8" => 0,
#              "One Plus 5T" => 0,
#      "Pixel 2 XL - Google" => 1,
#                "U11 - HTC" => 1,
#                 "V30 - LG" => 1,
#        "Xperia XZ1 - Sony" => 0,
#          "Z2 Force - Moto" => 0,
#     "ZenFone 4 Pro - Asus" => 1,
#         "iPhone X - Apple" => 2
# }
```

or, to receive the exact result as you wanted:

```
input.
  group_by { |h| h[:smartphone] }.
  map do |k, v|
    {smartphone: k, votes: v.reduce(0) { |acc, h| acc + h[:votes] }}
  end
```

Your code does not work because inside `Hash#merge` you have a typo `k == :vote` should read `k == :votes`.